# Using animated gif in splash screen vb.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, animation

I'm having trouble creating a .gif be animated in my already created visual studio 2013 project.

Been looking online a bit for the "proper" way to do it. Following this MSDN question: [Link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3fe32aae-84cb-47fe-a2b0-6650ce22e25c/splashscreen-that-loads-an-animated-gif?forum=vssmartdevicesvbcs) I copied some of the code to see how it would work. I've also seen references to using a timer.

```
 Public Not Inheritable Class SplashScreen

 Private progressGifPath As String = "C:\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CameraFinder\icons" + "\orangeLoading.gif"
Private _AnimatedGif As New Bitmap(progressGifPath)

Private m_IsAnimating As Boolean
Public Property IsAnimating() As Boolean
    Get
        Return m_IsAnimating
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As Boolean)
        m_IsAnimating = value
    End Set
End Property


Private Sub VICameraFinderLoading_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'Set up the dialog text at runtime according to the application's assembly information.  


    If My.Application.Info.Title <> "" Then

    Else

      End If


End Sub


Private Sub PlayGIF()
    If Not m_IsAnimating Then
         ImageAnimator.Animate(_AnimatedGif, New EventHandler(AddressOf    Me.OnFrameChanged))
        m_IsAnimating = True
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub OnFrameChanged(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    If m_IsAnimating Then
        ImageAnimator.UpdateFrames()
        Dim aGraphics As Graphics = PictureBox.CreateGraphics
        aGraphics.DrawImage(_AnimatedGif, New Point(30, 30))
        aGraphics.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub


End Class
```

So I tried this, but I don't see anything on the picture box drawn (I confirmed to see it was brought to the front). And apparently there can be a size limit to the gif included. Any ideas on what would be the better way to include it?

Thanks!

Comment: If you place an animated gif into a picturebox control you don't need to do anything else apart from showing it.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I hadn't set the image of the picture box to the gif.

EDIT:

To clarify, the code above wasn't the problem at all. I actually didn't need it in any way. I removed it from the splash screen class, completely. The solution was to go into my picture box's property  (F4) and set the backgroundImage to the .gif's filepath (thus importing it as an embedded resource). Doing so has allowed for animation in the splash screen.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Even if it's my own question?

Comment: Even if its your own question, you can either a) delete it, if it was simple and has no chance to help someone else, or b) answer it in a better way, i.e. show the code that helped you. This looks like it can help someone else, so probably show the code that didn't work and the code that worked and it will be OK.